# How to select select max value of one column for each month using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to make a report showing whether a project was completed in each month of the year.  It doesn't matter how many project were completed, just whether or not at least on project was completed.

```
with project_data as(
select '123' account, 'Started' status, to_date('01/01/2017','MM/DD/YY') 
sale_date from dual union all
select '123' account, 'Complete' status, to_date('01/15/2017','MM/DD/YY') 
sale_date from dual union all
select '123' account, 'Started' status, to_date('02/01/2017','MM/DD/YY') 
sale_date from dual union all
select '123' account, 'Complete' status, to_date('04/12/2017','MM/DD/YY') 
sale_date from dual union all
select '123' account, 'Complete' status, to_date('04/16/2017','MM/DD/YY') 
sale_date from dual)
```

From this example I would like the output to be like:

```
Account Completed Month Year
123     Yes       1     2017
123     No        2     2017
123     No        3     2017
123     Yes       4     2017
```

Comment: Do you need a row for a month that is not present in your input data (in your example, you show a row for Month value of 3, but there is no row with a date in March)? If so, the solution you accepted doesn't seem to do that. So - is your problem statement incorrect, or is the accepted answer actually not doing what you need?

Comment: The accepted answer did not do everything that I needed.  I accepted it because it was a good solution and will work for me but one requirement was missed.  I un-accepted the solution and commented.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( account, status, sale_date ) AS
  select '123', 'Started',  DATE '2017-01-01' from dual union all
  select '123', 'Complete', DATE '2017-01-15' from dual union all
  select '123', 'Started',  DATE '2017-02-01' from dual union all
  select '123', 'Complete', DATE '2017-04-12' from dual union all
  select '123', 'Complete', DATE '2017-04-16' from dual union all
  select '456', 'Complete', DATE '2017-03-28' from dual;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT,
       MONTH,
       CASE COUNT( CASE status WHEN 'Complete' THEN 1 END )
         WHEN 0
         THEN 'No'
         ELSE 'Yes'
       END AS Completed
FROM   ( SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ), LEVEL - 1 ) AS month
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YEAR' ), LEVEL - 1 ) <= SYSDATE )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table_name t
       PARTITION BY ( t.account )
       ON ( month <= sale_date AND sale_date < ADD_MONTHS( month, 1 ) )
GROUP BY Account, Month
ORDER BY Account, Month;
```

**Output**:

```
ACC MONTH               COM
--- ------------------- ---
123 2017-01-01 00:00:00 Yes
123 2017-02-01 00:00:00 No 
123 2017-03-01 00:00:00 No 
123 2017-04-01 00:00:00 Yes
456 2017-01-01 00:00:00 No 
456 2017-02-01 00:00:00 No 
456 2017-03-01 00:00:00 Yes
456 2017-04-01 00:00:00 No
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT YEAR,
       MONTH,
       ACCOUNT,
       CASE WHEN COMPLETED > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS AT_LEAST_ONE_COMP
  FROM (  SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SALE_DATE) AS YEAR,
                 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SALE_DATE) AS MONTH,
                 ACCOUNT,
                 SUM (CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    AS completed
            FROM MY_TABLE
        GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SALE_DATE),
                 EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SALE_DATE), 
                 ACCOUNT)
```

Comment: I would like to see if someone can propose a solution that accounts for March which is not returned in this solution.

Comment: The data that you provided does not include an entry for March.

Comment: Yes like my real life data.  So since there is no entry for March, I would like to show No.  I wouldn't want the report to not show a month.